# Select all records from a db if there modified date is greater or now using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am having an issue, that I am wondering can anyone help me with. I am creating a list from a  Database using Linq, I want to return all the records in a list that have been Modified on the current day.

The date was intaily set by:

> ```
>  contact.CreatedDate = System.DateTime.Now;
>  ctx.Contacts.Add(contact);'
> ```

When the record is updated the ModifiedDate is given a value.

```
  contact.ModifiedDate = System.DateTime.Now;
  ctx.Entry(contact).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Which is all fine the issue is below:

`var Contactlist = ctx.Contacts.Where(x => x.ModifiedDate = System.DateTime.Now
                                        ).ToList();`

Comment: What does `ModifiedDate` field contains? actual date? or date and time?

Comment: Double-equal... "==" operator. But with dates, you should probably not use strict equality if you want only the same day, not the same exact time. "System.DateTime.Now" *will* include the current time.

Comment: So what is the error?

Comment: Modified Date field contains "26/06/2014 15:56:02" Just the same day not the exact time, even better if i can get the same day and within the last hour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Entity framework [`EntityFunctions.TruncateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var Contactlist = ctx.Contacts.Where(x => 
                       EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ModifiedDate) == EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(System.DateTime.Today))
                       .ToList();
```

For LINQ to objects you could have compare the `Date` part only like:

```
var Contactlist = ctx.Contacts.Where(x => x.ModifiedDate.Date == System.DateTime.Today)
                              .ToList();
```

`DateTime` type object in .Net framework has `Date` as well as `Time` part, your current check would compare both date and time. *(Also you need `==` instead of `=`)*

`DateTime.Now` would return current date with current time, `DateTime.Today` will return your current date with time set to `00:00:00`. Similarly `DateTime.Date` would return the date part with time set to `00:00:00`, so you can use that for comparing date part only.

Comment: Modified Date field contains "26/06/2014 15:56:02" Just the same day not the exact time, even better if i can get the same day and within the last hour

Comment: If you want to compare time then calculate one hour before time like `DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);` and then use that in your query with check `x.ModifiedDate >= dt`